# How to use If with classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a calculator and the Operator keys have different color than the Number keys to distinguish them. I have this code that flashes a different color on mousedown and brings back their color on mouseup. 
I want to shorten it with an If stamement but i am not sure how. (all the keys flash the same color regardless of class on mousedown)

Could you use something like If->its Operator class->then bring back this color?

```
$('.number').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#363636');
  });
$('.number').mouseup(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#232323');
  });
$('.operator').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#363636');
  });
$('.operator').mouseup(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#1a1a1a');
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it using CSS

```
    .example {
    background-color: #232323; 
    }
    .example:active { 
    background-color: #363636; 
    }
```

Comment: Yes silly of me. I haven't been using css for a bit and totally forgot about active

Answer (score 1):

Use `jQuery.hasClass`

```
$('.number, .operators').mousedown(function() {
    var  $this = $(this);
      If ($this.hasClass("number")) $this.css('background-color', '#363636');
    else $this.css('background-color', '#363636')
 });
```

Comment: Yes that works perfectly. I will use it further but i think tweaking the css for now will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

So combine it down to a common selector and a check of the type

```js
$('button').on("mousedown mouseup", function(e) {
  var color = e.type === "mousedown" ? '#998877' : '#001122'
  $(this).css('background-color', color);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>a</button>
<button>b</button>
```